# No changes apply in "styleAnimationDuration" in a select

Tags: javascript

I am doing a Javascript exercise in which two images have to be superimposed, (an airplane flying over a beach). In it I must stop and start the animation and also be able to select the speed of the animation.

The first two functions (start and stop), work correctly, but not change the speed, are the following:

```
var playa = undefined;

window.onload = function () {
    playa = document.getElementById("playa"); 
}

function parar() {
    playa.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    playa.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "paused";
    playa.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";    
}

function seguir() {
    playa.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    playa.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "running";
    playa.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";     
}

function velocidad(t) {

    var valor = t + "s";
    alert (valor);

    console.log(valor);

    playa.style.animationDuration = valor;
    playa.style.MozAnimationDuration = valor;
    playa.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = valor;   

    console.log(playa.style);

}
```

I change the speeds with the following select:

```
<select name="vel">
<option selected="selected" onclick="velocidad(4)">Normal</option>
 <option onclick="velocidad(10)">Muy lento</option>
 <option onclick="velocidad(8)">Lento</option>
 <option onclick="velocidad(2)">Rápido</option>
 <option onclick="velocidad(1)">Muy Rápido</option>
```

And the start and stop:

```
<input type="button" name="stop" value="stop" onclick="parar()" />
<input type="button" name="play" value="play" onclick="seguir()" />
```

The problem is when I press any selectable option, the value is not modified and changes are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your method on change of select option:

```
<select name="vel" onchange="velocidad()">
<option selected="selected" value=4>Normal</option>
 <option value=10>Muy lento</option>
 <option value=8>Lento</option>
 <option value=2>Rápido</option>
 <option value=1>Muy Rápido</option>
 </select>
```

In your method get the `value` of `selected option` and use that `value`.

javascript code for method velocidad:

```
function velocidad() {
  var e = document.getElementById("vel");
  var t = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
  var valor = t + "s";
  alert(valor);

  console.log(valor);

  playa.style.animationDuration = valor;
  playa.style.MozAnimationDuration = valor;
  playa.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = valor;

  console.log(playa.style);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the value is changing, but the problem is when i select the option, the function "velocidad" is not running and does not change the animation speed on the screen

Comment: What do you mean `value` is change but function `velocidad` is not running? I don't get this because value is changed by this method.

Comment: In the function "velocidad", playa.style.animationDuration = valor; "valor" is not taking the value and is not changing the speed of the animation.

Comment: I have edited the answer and updated code for method `velocidad`, so that it gets the `selected option value` and updates `valor` value.